# Regular expression for opposite of integer without leading zeros

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex for integers with leading zero and it works fine. I am using it like:

```
  value = value.replace(/[^0-9]/, '');
```

Now, I want another regex for integers without leading zero. So, I got the below mentioned regex from stackoverflow answer:

```
[1-9]+[0-9]*
```

As I am using `string.replace`, I have to invert the regex. So my final code looks like:

```
  value = value.replace(/^(?![1-9]+[0-9]*)$/, '');
```

But now resulting value is always `empty`.

**Expectations:**

User should be allowed to typein these examples:

```
123456
123
78
```

User should not be able to type in these characters:

```
0123
e44
02565
asdf
02asf
754ads
```

Also, if I get a regex for only decimals without leading 0 and no `e` and should work in `value.replace`, then it will be a bonus for me.

I don't know how to construct regex patterns. So, if this a very basic question, then please forgive me.

Comment: It isn't super clear what the overall goal of this code is, what are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: What are the contents of value variable before calling replace.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen Goal is that the user should not be allowed to enter anything except numbers without leading 0. Currently I want the user to enter integers. But in another field I want the user to enter a decimal number without leading 0.

Comment: @AlekhyaSatya value is a string, which will be entered by user. So, it can be anything of type string.

Comment: What is the replace for, are you trying to do a regex replace every time the input changes?

Comment: @Confuzing yes I am doing exactly that.

Comment: replace method in javascript should have two inputs.So please specify what you want to replace.

Comment: @AlekhyaSatya I want to replace the new character with empty string if adding that character to the previous string does not make sense to the regex.

Comment: @anubhava sure. Give me a minute.

Comment: @anubhava Can you please take a look at the updated question?

Comment: Then don't use replace method.Try to use test() method which matches the input.

Comment: You can try `/^[1-9]\d*$/`

Comment: @anubhava after using your regex, I always get empty string back.

Comment: Don't use `.replace`, use `.test()` or `.matches()` methods

Comment: replace returns the modified string where the pattern is replaced.Here you are replacing with empty string that is the reason you are obtaining empty string,is that the case even when there is no match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it in two steps.

First remove the leading part (remove anything which is not a 1-9 at the beginning)

```
value = value.replace(/^[^1-9]*/, '');
```

then remove the trailing parts (match any number(s) in the beginning and remove the rest)

```
value = value.replace(/(?![0-9]+).*/, '');
```

for decimals use this (credits drkunibar):

```
value = value.replace(/.*?([1-9]+[0-9]*[\.]{0,1}[0-9]*).*/,'$1');
```

Comment: Sounds tricky!!! Works like a charm. Thank you. Can you please provide me the same for decimal if possible?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
value = "e044".replace(/^.*?([1-9]+[0-9]*).*$/, '$1');
```

return 44

Comment: Actually this is a much nicer solution than the one I gave above and does exactly what you want. The '$1' part is important as it replaces everything with what was matched in between the parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
match = /^[1-9]\d*$/.test(value);
```

match will contain a boolean,true if the user enters a number without 0 in the lead,false-for anything other than number without 0 in the lead.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But my code is written in such a way, that I cannot use match or test as all other patterns in my code depends on replace and the function I am using is very generic for my project.